# Failed to create lease Leader/master/5.1.SearchGraph

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am getting following error in my datastax debug log. We had not created any new datacenter, only change we had made is snitch change to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch. We are using the same old name in /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties.

```
Failed to create lease Leader/master/5.1.SearchGraph.  Possible causes
include network/C* issues, the lease being disabled, insufficient 
replication (you created a new DC and didn't ALTER KEYSPACE dse_leases)   
and the duration (30000) being different (you have to disable/delete
/recreate the lease to change the duration). java.io.IOException: No live 
replicas for lease Leader/master/5.1.SearchGraph in table   
dse_leases.leases (keyspace dse_leases has no replicas in datacenter 
SearchGraph!  You need to adjust the replication factor.
```

Comment: What instruction did you follow to change the snitch was it http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSwitchSnitch.html

Comment: what did you change with the GPFS?  Could you provide more details please?

Comment: @mando222 Yes we followed the steps mentioned your in datastax document.

Comment: @jlacefie Ye we are currently using  endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch previously it was SimpleSnitch. We are using network topology with replication factor 2.Currently i have 3 datastatx nodes in our datacenter.

Comment: @jlacefie We had changed DC name to SearchGraph, which is same as before changing snitch from Simplesnitch to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you have some stale or non matching data in your system tables from changing the DC name.  The easiest thing to do to remedy this, if this is a dev environment or a prod environment with no data, is to wipe your Cassandra data directories and restart your nodes.

Comment: There is  data in the nodes,so i can't wipe the data in directories

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  If not, you can backup data from the data directories or simply copy off the data director contents, rebuild the cluster, and load the data back into the cluster using sstableloader.